# Access image URL in Umbraco 8

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

I've been trying to utilise Umbraco 8 in a new project. (I've got C# experience but never used Umbraco before)

I've added templates and set it up to accept data, however I've set up a "Home" DocType and added an Image Selector. 
After setting and publishing the data, I'm now trying to update the template to display the Image, and keep running into errors, I've tried:

```
var backgroundImageId = Model.Value("backgroundImage");
var backgroundImage = Umbraco.Media(backgroundImageId);
```

```
@Model.Value("backgroundImage").Url
```

And a bunch of others which haven't panned out. I just can't seem to get it to work.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var backgroundImage = Model.Value<IPublishedContent>("backgroundImage").Url;
```

Fouund the solution to this, converting the type to published content seems to do the trick.

Comment: Checkout models builder, it enables strongly typed models. So you could of just done what would of made sense to you with C# i.e.  @Model.BackgroundImage.Url

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can get this.

```
IPublishedContent contentbackgroundImage = umbracoHelper.TypedContent(backgroundImageId);

var backgroundImage = contentbackgroundImage?.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("backgroundImage");
```

you can do like this way on the razor pages

```
@{
    var backgroundImage = Model.GetValue<IPublishedContent>("backgroundImage")
}
```

from this you can access properies like url, name ,alies ect.

Comment: I believe this is for Umbraco 7, not 8.